# How do you use @Inject with an ejb-jar with (one or more) WAR files?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

Working with GlassFish, trying to be tidy, I would like to put all of my business logic into a single EJB JAR. I then have 2 WAR files.

- app-frontend-war
- app-backend-war
- app-logic-ejb

Each of the WAR files need to use the EJBs that are within the app-logic-ejb JAR. This EJB JAR holds the main persistence unit. But I am finding that @Inject of any app-logic-ejb EJB's from any Java within the WAR files are not working.

Also, I am trying to avoid using an EAR.

Comment: This can't be working cause WAR does not have such concept. Using EAR is the path you have to go...Add both war files to the EAR files (check for skinnyWars options) and the `@Inject` will do it's work.

Comment: Thank you @khmarbaise for getting back to me. I tried this but it did not work for me.

Comment: I gave it one more go and found it worked thank you @khmarbaise. However, the second time I tried was without "check for skinnyWars options". What is the skinnyWars option for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the [Java EE 7 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-intro004.htm) I have finally worked it out.

Even though the beans in app-logic-ejb are on the same GlassFish they need to be annotated as remote beans. The WAR files then use @EJB injection (instead of @Inject) into the correct interface within the WAR file.

```
@EJB
TestBeanInterface t;
```

To share the interface between the EJB JAR and the War files a Java Library is needed.

So to make it work it turns out I need:

- **app-library**
- app-logic-ejb
- app-frontend-war
- app-backend-war